# Picking the next timer value from an array of periodic timers

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a list of clients say (A,B,C,D) that have their own time periods/windows. I set a timer internally based on the next window expiry... from among (A,B,C,D)'s window sizes..

For example:

```
Client Window Size
A      10
B      15
C      20
D      50
```

So timer expiry is going to be: 10,15,20,30,40,45,50 ...

What's the best way to do this? Choosing C as our language to implement. Client Periods are stored in a statically allocated array (we know the size)

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is a priority (min) heap, with the priority based on expiration time.

Each time a window expires, remove the min item from the heap in O(1) time, and reinsert at the expiration time plus the window size in O(log(N)) time. The space required is O(N).

To represent the present time there are (at least) two options.

1) Use a wide value (say 64 bits) that will handle time until the Sun flames out

2) Use modulo arithmetic; this requires a careful comparison operator

For the modulo approach, the time value must at least as big as the largest window size plus a small margin for timer expiration latency. Use unsigned arithmetic. The value in the heap should be the time the entry is inserted. The time remaining for each entry is

```
window - (now - inserted)
```

Note that `(now - inserted)` is always positive since it's a measure of how long the entry's been in the heap -- if the difference "wraps" zero the unsigned result will be correct; `window` is also positive. If we have two entries `x` and `y` we want to see if

```
(x.window - (now - x.inserted)) > (y.window - (now - y.inserted))
```

We can do this with unsigned arithmetic using

```
(x.window + (now - y.inserted)) > (y.window + (now - x.inserted))
```

This is the comparison operator we use to compare heap entries.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how often you add clients and how window sizes are big I would consider using this approach:

1. Define m as highest Window Size: `m = max(Window Size)`.
2. Then you can allocate array of booleans: `bool Alarms[m]`.
3. For each client set: `Alamrs[k*windowsize]=true` where `k` is in range `<1, m/windowsize>`

   - in your example Alarms will look like:
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
     Alarms[10]=true;
     Alarms[15]=true;
     Alarms[20]=true;
     Alarms[30]=true;
     etc.

Every tick of alarm check `Alarms[tick % m]` for its value. When you read true alarm should ring up. Reading status is O(1).

This approach is good when Window Sizes are similar and you dont add clients with higher Window Size very often.

- when adding client with Window Size > m you have to reallocate whole array which could be expensive.
- when there are large spaces between client windows - for example A=1 and B=30000 you would need 29998 empty cells.